# Why is an AdvancedMarker not being added to a map, even though MapCapabilities says they are supported?

Tags: android, google-maps

In my Android Activity I am adding a custom marker to a map. If `AdvancedMarkers` are available, I create one with an `ImageView` displaying a `Drawable`, if not, I fall back to a normal `Marker` in the given colour:

```
Marker marker;
MapCapabilities mapCapabilities = map.getMapCapabilities();
if (mapCapabilities.isAdvancedMarkersAvailable()) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MyActivity.this);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(MyActivity.this, R.drawable.hello));
    ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(imageView, ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(MyActivity.this, color)));
    marker = map.addMarker(new AdvancedMarkerOptions().position(position).title("My Title").iconView(imageView).zIndex(999));
} else {
   MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(position).title("My Title").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(hue));
   marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

On a virtual device with API level 33, the first code block is triggered and the `AdvancedMarker` is correctly added.

On a physical device with API level 29, however, the first code block is still triggered - so `AdvancedMarkers` should technically be available - but the marker that is created is just a default red pin.

It's not even like the second code block is being triggered and it's deliberately creating a normal `Marker` with the colour I specified - it's saying it can create an `AdvancedMarker` and then just creating something that's neither here nor there.

I don't know why this is.

Comment: Seeing the exact same issue.

Comment: It would be good for you to file a bug in the Public Issue Tracker. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker